# Call To A Member Function On String

Tags: laravel, function, member-functions

Hello Guys I Have This Function In My Model

```
public  function photo () {
      return  $this -> photo;
}
```

And I Called The Function From My Blade

```
{{$model = \App\Models\mainCategory::class}}

<td> <img style="width: 150px; height: 100px;" src="{{asset('assets/images/main-categories/' . $model -> photo() // Here I Have an Error `Call to a member function photo() on string`  )}}"></td>
```

I Have This Error `Call to a member function photo() on string`

Comment: Try to dd() $model variable and you see that this is a full name (with a namespace) of a mainCategory class, and it is a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
use App\Models\mainCategory;

class YourController extends Controller
{

   public function index(){
      return view('your_view', ['category' => mainCategory::first() ];
   }
}
```

Then in your blade file, you do:

```php
$category->photo
```

Instead of your current model->photo()

Answer (score 0):

This line `{{$model = \App\Models\mainCategory::class}}`  is wrong. You have first to retrieve the model from the database, to use the model attributes.
For example 
`{{$model = \App\Models\mainCategory::first()}}` or
`{{$model = \App\Models\mainCategory::find($id)}}`. 
Another thing to point, since you have the attribute `photo` already existing, why would write a method, that returns the same thing. You can use `$model->photo` directly. 
Another thing, it's not recommended to retrieve data from the database, while you're in the view, you have the controller to do so.

Comment: Undefined variable $id